# R TwitteR package authorization error

Tags: r, twitter-oauth

I am following the latest update on [twitteR homepage](https://github.com/geoffjentry/twitteR), and I can't pass the authorization process.

```
library(devtools)
install_github("twitteR", username="geoffjentry")

library(twitteR)
api_key <-  "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
api_secret <- "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
access_token <- "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
access_secret <- "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
setup_twitter_oauth(api_key, api_secret, access_token, access_secret)
```

This is the output I am getting back:

```
[1] "Using direct authentication"
Error in check_twitter_oauth() : OAuth authentication error:
This most likely means that you have incorrectly called setup_twitter_oauth()'
```

I have also tried `setup_twitter_oauth(api_key, api_secret)`, and this is the error message:

```
[1] "Using browser based authentication"
Error in init_oauth1.0(endpoint, app, permission = params$permission) : 
client error: (401) Unauthorized
```

I don't think there are any other options in [`setup_twitter_oauth`](https://github.com/geoffjentry/twitteR/blob/master/man/setup_twitter_oauth.Rd). Does anyone else encounter this error?

Comment: You have acquired your own api key and access token, right? You're not just using "X"'s in practice? This will be very hard to debug without a reproducible error.

Comment: @MrFlick Yes, I have my own api key and access token. I am just using "X" as placeholder. Is there a way to trace back the error?

Comment: This question seems specific to the package. I'd recommend seeking help on the [twitteR mailing list](http://lists.hexdump.org/listinfo.cgi/twitter-users-hexdump.org) or if you believe the error is reproducible, create a [twitteR github issue](https://github.com/geoffjentry/twitteR/issues). Make sure you are running a current version of `httr` as well.

Comment: There is one thing which I just found out - 1. Don't use Proxy settings. 2. Don't tick "Enable callback Locking" in settings. it might help

Answer (score 15, accepted):

set callback url to http://127.0.0.1:1410 in app settings in twitter

Comment: If you're suggesting that based on [this issue](https://github.com/hadley/httr/issues/156), it would help to include that as context.

Answer (score 6):

This error happens when your app is missing the callback url. To solve this issue go to https://apps.twitter.com/ select your application and then go to **SETTINGS** scroll down to **CALLBACK URL** and enter ( http://127.0.0.1:1410 ). This should allow you to run browser verification.

[image]

Or you can enter the **access_token** and **access_secret** in R to trigger local verification.

```
 consumer_key   <- " YOUR CONSUMER KEY "
 consumer_secret<- " YOUR CONSUMER SECRET "
 access_token   <- " YOUR ACCESS TOKEN "
 access_secret  <- " YOUR ACCESS SECRET "
 setup_twitter_oauth(consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token, access_secret)
```

Answer (score 5):

I have tried  setting call back URL to ( http://127.0.0.1:1410 ), updating all packages related to this package. Nothing solved my problem.
then i installed httk httpuv packages and did the lines below:

```
consumer_key <- " YOUR CONSUMER KEY "
consumer_secret<- " YOUR CONSUMER SECRET"
setup_twitter_oauth(consumer_key, consumer_secret,
                    access_token=NULL, access_secret=NULL)
```

It worked like a beauty.

Doing the above takes to a web page and you manually authorize the app.
While this may not be the solution to the question, it is definitely a workaround to the authentication roadblock.

Answer (score 3):

try `install.packages('base64enc')` . it worked for me. found it in github discussion.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Tried all the suggestions I found on the net but in vain.

Probably it has to do with the Callback URL, I had skipped it earlier.

Created a new app, this time included it - http://127.0.0.1:1410 and it worked for me.

Here is the code I used:

```
library(httr)
library(devtools)
library(twitteR)
library(base64enc)

consumer_key <- 'XXXXXXXXXXXX'
consumer_secret <- 'XXXXXXXXXXXX'
access_token <- 'XXXXXXXXXXXX'
access_secret <- 'XXXXXXXXXXXX'
setup_twitter_oauth(consumer_key , consumer_secret, access_token, access_secret)

tw <- searchTwitter("LFC",n=100,lang="en")
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and tried all latest httr download and libraries but still the problem was there. Then I created a new APP in twitter and used API keys and other credentials in the code and now the problem solved. 
I was using an APP which i created 8 months back ....regenerating the API credentials may also solve for the existing APP.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this

setup_twitter_oauth(apiKey, apiSecret, access_token = accessToken, access_secret = accessSecret)

Answer (score 0):

I got it fixed by manually generating access token at apps.twitter.com site and pass that as argument to the api which will force to use local authentication rather than browser authentication.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error:
"Error in check_twitter_oauth() : OAuth authentication error:
This most likely means that you have incorrectly called setup_twitter_oauth()'"
and after trying the different solutions posted here in the stackoverflow, I still did not get the problem solved. I have regenerated my consumer key and consumer secret and supplied it to the following lines in my R script:

```
consumer_key <- 'XXconsumer_keyXX'
consumer_secret <- 'XXconsumer_secretXX'
access_token <- 'XXaccess_tokenXX'
access_secret <- 'XXaccess_secretXX'
setup_twitter_oauth(consumer_key , consumer_secret, access_token, access_secret)
```

What I did to get it right and get the OAuth authentication handshake is to supply the twitter supplied consumer key, consumer secret, access token, access secret value directly to the 5th line above, that is,

```
setup_twitter_oauth("xxconsumer_key_xx", "xxconsumer_secretxx", "xxaccess_tokenxx", "xxaccess_secretxx")
```

This works for me and hope it will for you.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this issue and went through everything posted here to no avail. I finally looked at Windows Firewall and realized I had not made an exception for Rstudio. Everything works now!